# How to export a python function in R package development using reticulate?

Tags: r, reticulate

Can I export a python function like Rcpp by adding this line before a function:
// [[Rcpp::export]]

Answer (score 0):

This does not work the exact same way.

But you can write an R function which, using reticulate, access a Python function, has it compute its return value, and provide that to R.  That R helper function can then be provided just like any other R function.